# Distribution of cards(simulation in r)

Tags: r

This is a vector of cards:

```
Cards
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[35] 10 11 12 13 14  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
```

1:14 - cards values:

I want to distribute this cards among 2 players: 26 cards for both of them.

```
hand_1 <- sample(cards,size = length(cards)/2)
```

this is a hand for player 1.

How can I get the hand for player 2 correctly? I need somehow delete all elements from `cards`, that exist in `hand_1`. How can i do this without using loop technique.

Comment: `hand_2 <- sample(cards[!cards %in% hand_1], size=length(cards)/2)` maybe?

Comment: Oops!  okay then `split(cards, sample(rep(1:2, length(cards) / 2)))`

Comment: Removed the comment and posted an answer I think is better.

Comment: @Carl your code produce an error: cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Comment: @RichScriven thank you! Very good and clean answer:)

Comment: `hand_2 <- sample(cards[!cards %in% hand_1], size=(length(cards)/2)-1)` then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply:

```
matrix(sample(cards),ncol=2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("hand1","hand2")))
```

so you get a `matrix` whose columns are the two hands.

Comment: Very elegant:) Thank you!